# Sequelize – autocompletion for methods and attributes

Tags: javascript, sequelize.js

This is my current setup:

```js
const { Model, DataTypes } = require('sequelize');

class CustomModel extends Model {
  static init(attributes, config) {
    return super.init(attributes, {
      ...config,
      timestamps: true,
      underscored: true,
      createdAt: 'created_at',
      updatedAt: 'updated_at',
    });
  }
}

class User extends CustomModel {
  ahoy() {
    const { email } = this.get();
    console.log(`Ahoy, ${email}`);
  }
}

User.init({
  id: {
    type: DataTypes.UUID,
    primaryKey: true,
    allowNull: false,
    defaultValue: DataTypes.UUIDV4,
  },
  email: {
    type: DataTypes.STRING,
    allowNull: false,
    unique: true
  },
}, myConfigHere);
```

I now want to ensure that all `User` attributes, as well as its model methods, are showing up in VSCode autocomplete. How can I make this happen?

```js
const user = await User.findOne({ where: { email: 'john@example.com' } });
user.email; // No autocomplete while typing
user.ahoy() // No autocomplete while typing
```

When I change the code to `class User extends Model`, then I can see the `ahoy()` being autocompleted, yet this does not apply to `.email`

Is there a way to fix this (e.g. with JSDoc)?

Answer (score 0):

Some sort of solution can be:

```
// in file /models/user.js

// 1. Put your user properties in an object
const userProperties = {
id: {
    type: DataTypes.UUID,
    primaryKey: true,
    allowNull: false,
    defaultValue: DataTypes.UUIDV4,
  },
  email: {
    type: DataTypes.STRING,
    allowNull: false,
    unique: true
  }
}

// 2. Init your model with:
User.init(userProperties, myConfigHere)


// 3. Create the User type with:
/**
 * @typedef {import('sequelize').Model & userProperties} User
 */
```

Now if you have a User instance object, you just need to specify its type with:

```
// in file /someFolder/someScript.js

/** @type {import('../models/user.js').User[]} */
let allUsers = User.findAll()
```

That way, you will have code suggestions with both the sequelize normal model methods (like .save(), .destroy() ...) and your properties.

Not perfect, but that's what I use.

Answer (score -1):

If you are using pure Javascript you won't be able to do that.
Consider using Typescript, then VSCode (or any editor really) will be able to watch your Object and suggest what attribute you want from it.